# Dapper and .net core 3

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

Im new to .netcore and trying to use dapper for some db interactions. Does dapper not work with .net core 3? Or am I doing something wrong :X

I created a new .net project:

```
dotnet new mvc
```

tried to add dapper

```
dotnet add package Dapper --version 2.0.30
```

Then I get the error:

```
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Dapper' into project 
 C:\repos\dapper\dapper.csproj'.

info : Restoring packages for C:\repos\dapper\dapper.csproj...
error: Cycle detected.

error:   dapper -> Dapper (>= 2.0.30).

info : Package 'Dapper' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'C:\repos\dapper\dapper.csproj'.

error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that csproj has the same name as the dependant PackageReference `dapper`,refer to https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6754

> A project and a dependency cannot have the same name.

Change the name of your project(not using `dapper`) will overcome it.